# Many input parameters to a binary file

Tags: python, c++, parsing, io

I have a simulation program written in C++. Normally, I would want to initialize the binary code with different parameters for different runs. First I tried using all my input parameters as command line arguments, but it happened to be too confusing, there are just too many parameters. Like:

```
./mysimulation 5 55 True ... output_file_name.txt
```

Then I decided to parse only a filename with input parameters written in it.
Like:

```
./mysimulation input_parameters.txt
```

But then the input file looks messy and confuses me because there are multiple lines, but I forget what lines correspond to what parameters The file would like so:

```
input_parameters.txt
55
5
True
...
output_file_name.txt
```

I could add comments, but then it is going to be a hassle to handle input file in C++, as it will require additional effort to parse the parameters in the file.

Now, I thought about using XML files since they are very structured and human-readable. I'm not sure if it is going to be easy to generate these XML files in python (python generates input parameters and launches C++ code multiple times) and read them in C++. Maybe there exists a better solution?

In my future plans, I'd like to have a parallel execution of multiple binaries on a many-CPU server computer. It'd be nice if the solution nicely complied with multiprocessing extension.

I tried linking C++ and Python with boost (as I did with my other projects), but I had trouble setting it up these CMakeFiles as the C++ has multiple classes, and I gave up after a couple of hours. And in one of my projects after making a shared library, multiprocessing with python crashed when using these libraries for some unknown to me reason, that is why I'd like to avoid python boost. (Maybe I did something incorrectly)

Comment: I would store the data as JSON (which lets you label the parameters), and then use a JSON library to parse it into C++

Comment: "additional effort to parse the parameters in the file. " -- Consider if you define the comments (in your input file) to use C++ style, i.e. '"// to end of line", This comment is trivial to remove.  So read in the line, scan for "//', and then erase to end of line.  Now you got your 'messy' input file.  And good comments should help readability.